How can I access the Solr security panel?
I use solr on windows, I wanted to create a file security.json in order to access the security panel. I think I put the json in the right place (-Dsolr.solr.home) but when I launch my solr, nothing changes from before, no authentication, nothing. In the security tab it says "Current user is not authenticated! Security panel is disabled." Here are the contents of my json
{
    "authentication":{
       "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
       "credentials":{"solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="}
    },
    "authorization":{
       "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
       "user-role":{"solr":"admin"},
       "permissions":[{"name":"security-edit",
                      "role":"admin"}]
}}

Thank you in advance for your help.
